# Configure Network User Authentication with SSSD in Ubuntu

Tags: pam, sssd

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu and have zero experience in configuring SSSD.  Recently I configured an Ubuntu machine to authenticate network user with SSSD-AD.  I followed the guide in https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd-ad and so far I managed to add the Ubuntu machine to the AD domain.  getent returned AD objects correctly.
However when I performed an SSH to the server, I got inconsistent results.  Sometimes I managed to login, and sometimes it failed.

Below is the output of /var/log/auth.log with username, IP and domain name altered.

For a successful login:

```
May 11 03:29:31 ubuntu01 sshd[3085401]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.60.217.155  user=user1@abcd.com
May 11 03:29:31 ubuntu01 sshd[3085401]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.60.217.155 user=user1@abcd.com
May 11 03:29:33 ubuntu01 sshd[3085401]: Accepted password for user1@abcd.com from 10.60.217.155 port 52525 ssh2
May 11 03:29:33 ubuntu01 sshd[3085401]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user1@abcd.com by (uid=0)
May 11 03:29:33 ubuntu01 sshd[3085401]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: No such process
```

For an unsuccessful login, the ssh client will just wait till it was timed-out:

```
May 11 03:32:27 ubuntu01 sshd[3085589]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.60.217.155  user1@abcd.com
May 11 03:32:27 ubuntu01 sshd[3085589]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.60.217.155 user=user1@abcd.com
May 11 03:33:57 ubuntu01 sshd[3085589]: Failed password for user1@abcd.com from 10.60.217.155 port 52534 ssh2
May 11 03:33:57 ubuntu01 sshd[3085589]: fatal: Access denied for user user1@abcd.com by PAM account configuration [preauth]
May 11 03:34:38 ubuntu01 sssd_be[3065663]: Warning: user would have been denied GPO-based logon access if the ad_gpo_access_control option were set to enforcing mode.
May 11 03:35:01 ubuntu01 CRON[3085606]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 11 03:35:01 ubuntu01 CRON[3085606]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

The warning from sssd_be can be ignored, as I've set ad_gpo_access_control = permissive in the sssd.conf file.

Many thanks in advance for your insight.

regards,
bongsf